# Parsing JSON where String has Apostrophe Right at Beginning of Property Value - Next to Quotation Mark

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble parsing a string into a JSON object. The troublesome aspect is two-fold:

1. there is a phrase surrounded by quotes ; and
2. that phrase appears at the very beginning of the string - so
   immediately after a quote character.

I have some server code which renders into my page the following into an inline script element:

```
var str = '[{"Id":null,"Name":"\"A gamma\" bla bla rest of string","Code":null,"OtherBits":null,"IsActive":true,}]';
```

So you can see, the problem is the string value for the **"Name"** property.

The only thing I have so far which works is as follows, but obviously it is hard-coded and only works with that example:

```
var str = '[{"Id":null,"Name":"\"A gamma\" bla bla rest of string","Code":null,"OtherBits":null,"IsActive":true,}]';
var escapedString = str.replace('"\"', '"\\"');
var escapedString2 = escapedString.replace('a\"', 'a\\"');
var existingDataForItems = JSON.parse(escapedString2);
```

I need to generalize it.

Note, you would think it would be as simple as:

```
var escapedString = str.replace('\"', '\\"');
```

It is not. That does not work.

Comment: Not your current problem but your JSON also has a trailing comma at the end of the first array item.

Comment: Then the root of the problem is the rendering of that string on to the page. Solve that problem instead of working around it.

Comment: Any reason your server-side script doesn't just render `var obj = [{"Id":null,...`. If it were say PHP, it would look like `var obj = <?= json_encode($someArray) ?>;`. There's really no need to do any string parsing

Comment: @Phil Yep, that worked. I could not see the wood for the trees on that one. Inherited code-base. Thanks. Make answer and will anoint it so.

Comment: To clarify: The problem is not with the JSON. The problem is thats you are putting JSON inside a *string literal*.  A string literal has its own set of special characters. As such you would have to escape the JSON to be used inside a string literal first. Simplified example: `["'"]` is valid JSON. Put inside a string literal we have a syntax error: `'["'"]'`. However, as said, there is actually no need to put it inside a string literal in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, just assign an object / array literal instead of attempting to wrap it in a string and parse it.

From the comments it seems you're using PHP so assuming you have a server-side array `$data`...

```
var existingDataForItems = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
```

This will result in something like (formatting added for clarity)

```
var existingDataForItems = [{
    "Id": null,
    "Name": "\"A gamma\" bla bla rest of string",
    "Code": null,
    "OtherBits": null,
    "IsActive": true
}];
```